# how to remove the background image using jquery with class name

Tags: jquery, html, class, background-image

I'm trying to remove the background image using jquery.But its not happening, But using the same format i can change the background color

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 
{
background-image:url('paper.gif');
background-color:#cccccc;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("h1").each(function( index ) {
    $("."+$(this).attr("class")).css('background-image' , 'none');

    });

});
</script>
</head>


<h1 class="RED">This is a heading</h1>
<h1 class="YELLOW">This is a heading</h1>
<h1 class="RED">This is a heading</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: try `''` instead of `'none'`

Comment: @Mr.coder- Sorry ,it didn't work

Comment: try @Aaron's solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7gZM7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



     $("h1").each(function( index ) {
     $("."+$(this).attr("class")).css({"background":"none"});



    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the class part, try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").css({'background-image' , 'none'});
});
</script>
```

In jQuery, you aren't modifying the stylesheet, you are modifying the DOM after the stylesheet has been applied, so just attack the element directly.

Comment: Sorry, I cleaned it up and added the {} brackets, that should work now.

Comment: The alternative to try, would be rather than assign the background to h1, assign it to a class, and then you can toggle the class like $(".h1WithBackground").removeClass("h1WithBackground");

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('h1').css('background-image', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have removeAttr , you may remove all styles definitions with:

`$('h1').removeAttr('style');`